# GPIO extension - USB to GPIO module (NOT GPIO to USB)

Tags: gpio, hardware

I ran out of GPIO on my RPI and now looking for a module to converts USB to GPIO for my Raspberry. I am not interested in converting GPIO to USB, but interested in USB to GPIO.
I've been googling for some time but haven't found anything like this. Do you maybe know if a product like this exists, that I can connect to my raspberry, and use some extra, additional GPIO ports?

Comment: https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/ryanteck-rtk-gpio-pc-gpio-interface or https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264

Answer (score 1):

You can connect a Pi Zero via USB to your current Pi.  That will give you 26 additional GPIO.

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pi_zero_otg.html

Answer (score -1):

You are extremely unlikely to find any such device.

Most of us would use a GPIO extender. There are several that work over I²C.